# How to do logging of C# Console application using EL 6.0

Tags: c#, logging, listener, enterprise-library

Can any one let me know how to implement logging with *Enterprise Library 6.0* in C#. I want to do logging in Database, if it is available otherwise log the exceptions , information, messages into LOG file.
Can anyone tell me  How to implement logging into Db, otherwise log in file dynamically.
I will have both logging DB and file config changes in `App.config`/`Web.config`.
So please help me on this how to implement logging dynamically based on runtime value:
*If Db is available and accessible, then log, otherwise if DB is not accessible, then log to Log-file or event-viewer.*

Answer (score 0):

The new version 6 makes comprehensive use of the factory pattern, hence you need to set the logger up differently in version 6:

- Try the following:

  ```
  IConfigurationSource configsrc = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
  LogWriterFactory logWriterFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configsrc);
  Logger.SetLogWriter(logWriterFactory.Create());

  Logger.Write("logtest", "General");
  ```
- Your description of your database logging requirements isn't quite clear, but I think [these Code examples and links](http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/enterprise-library-basic-semantic-logging-database/) should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Lo, Thanks for answering the question, Basically i will have functionality of logging in File and Database same. Only change, is if the database is available, log the errors, exceptions & warning into database , if it not available log the details into File.